# searching in a part of word with Sphinx

Tags: search, sphinx

I need to configure Sphinx to search for parts of word, not whole. It's written on the [official site](http://sphinxsearch.com/info/faq/#substring-search), that I should use directives
'min_infix_len', 'min_prefix_len' and 'enable_star'. Actually, all registered in the config file.

But search in a word part doesn't work.
`*` in the beginning or end of a word is not helping.

```
source src1
{

  type= mysql
  sql_host= localhost
  sql_user= root
  sql_pass=
  sql_db= ajax
  sql_port= 3306

  sql_query= \
    SELECT id, bookauthor FROM authors
    sql_query_info= SELECT * FROM authors WHERE id=$id
}


index index1
{
  source= src1
  path = /var/data/src1
  morphology =stem_en
  min_word_len = 1
  charset_type = sbcs
  enable_star=1
  min_infix_len =3
  min_prefix_len = 3
}

searchd
{
  listen = 9312
  log = /var/log/searchd.log
  query_log = /var/log/query.log
  pid_file = /var/log/searchd.pid
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only implement one of them

min_infix_len =3
min_prefix_len = 3

Prefix is for *something

Infix can be used with everything..

Remove one of them

Comment: do you need to restart the searchd process?

Comment: @IonutFlaviusPogacian No, just re-run the indexer.