# SphinxQL - Sphinx search for a part of word

Tags: php, sphinx

My current Sphinx configurations only returns results matching the whole words, but i would like sphinx to return search for parts of word too.

e.g.
if i search for word
block
it should return result containng all words whic contains word block and not just exat matches.
e.g.
blockbuster
megablockbuster
megablock

its simillar to using *block* in query

my current SPhinxQL query looks like this

```
SELECT id FROM disk_index1 WHERE MATCH('block') LIMIT 0,25 OPTION max_matches = 10000
```

i have tried answer from 
ref: [searching in a part of word with Sphinx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5456413/searching-in-a-part-of-word-with-sphinx)

```
  enable_star=1
```

but 
its depreciated now.
i have even tried running query like this

```
SELECT id FROM disk_index1 WHERE MATCH('*block*') LIMIT 0,25 OPTION max_matches = 10000
```

but still it doesnt returns partial words matches

How can i enable partial word matches ? in SPhinxQL ?

Sphinx Server version: 2.2.9-id64-release (rel22-r5006)
on Cent Os 7 x 64

my current index configuration has

```
docinfo                 = extern
morphology              = stem_en
enable_star = 1
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `min_infix_len` and `min_prefix_len` to achieve this:

> Infix length setting enables wildcard searches with term patterns like
>   'start*', '*end', '*middle*', and so on. It also lets you disable too
>   short wildcards if those are too expensive to search for.

Read more on [Sphinx Search current documentation](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#conf-min-prefix-len).